# Specify context from where comes term in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ambiguous, explicit-specialization

Here is a dummy example:

```
class Test a b where
  witness :: a

f :: Test a b => a
f = witness
```

Haskell then say

```
Could not deduce (Test a b0) arising from a use of ‘witness’
from the context (Test a b)
  bound by the type signature for f :: Test a b => a
  at test.hs:8:6-18
The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include f :: a (bound at test.hs:9:1)
In the expression: witness
In an equation for ‘f’: f = witness
```

Error comes from the fact that Haskell cannot infer type variable `b0` and a solution would be to remove parameter `b` from definition of the typeclass `Test`. But, in reality, I cannot.

My question is : Does it exist a way to explicity identify `b0` with explicit parameter `b` given in line `f :: Test a b => a`?

Thanks.

Comment: Is adding a `Proxy b` argument (or even `proxy b`) to `witness` an option?

Comment: Alternatively, is adding a functional dependency `a -> b` an option?

Comment: Or change it to `witness :: Constant a b`

Answer (score 1):

Fleshing out [Joachim Breitner's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958506/specify-context-from-where-comes-term-in-haskell#comment55674864_33958506), you could use `witness` if you can alter its type signature to be `proxy b -> a` argument or `Constant a b`.

The two approaches are mostly equivalent, so it's a matter of preference:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module SO33958506 where

import Data.Functor.Constant
import Data.Proxy

class Test a b where
  constantWitness :: Constant a b
  proxyWitness :: proxy b -> a

constantWitnessWithProxy :: forall proxy a b. Test a b => proxy b -> a
constantWitnessWithProxy _ = getConstant $ (constantWitness :: Constant a b)

proxyWitnessAsConstant :: forall a b. Test a b => Constant a b
proxyWitnessAsConstant = Constant $ proxyWitness (Proxy :: Proxy b)
```

Comment: Thank you all! But what Constant and proxy type constructors are for?

Comment: They bring the `b` type into scope, so the compiler knows which instance of `Test a b` to use. If only `a` is in scope, it has no way of determining which instance to use, since there may be `Test a b` instances for multiple different `b`s, given an `a`.